# Installshield custom action error

Tags: installshield

I have a custom action that no longer exists (I deleted it and it is no-where to be seen at all in [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield). I compile and rebuild InstallShield. When I click "Run" to install the product, it gets close to the end, then spouts:

> error #1721: Cannot execute "Run_exe.exe".

The custom action no longer exists, and it still seems to attempt to run it... I took it out of the list of events as well. Why is it doing this when I have completely removed it?

Comment: What is the project type, MSI or InstallScriptMSI?

Answer (score 3):

If your ISM file is stored in the XML format, I would open the ISM file with a text editor and search for the name of the custom action. That should indicate where it is still being referenced.

Comment: If your ism is not currently stored as xml, you could create a copy of the project and convert the ism to xml.

Comment: If your ism is not stored as XML, your source control of the file is going to be fairly useless (for showing changes between checkins). You are using source control right?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it didn't truly get deleted?  Try going through InstallShield's "Direct Editor".  Go to the "CustomAction" table.  Right-click the custom action you want removed and select "Drop row".

Answer (score 0):

I get errors like that cropping up all the time, because I make a lot of changes to the installer from version to version. The only way I've found to deal with it is to start a new project and copy all the properties from one to the other. Not very efficient, granted, but it's better than nothing.